# Akka.net Adds a random number to Actor name under /user

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka-cluster

i have An actor that i want to Access remotely but Akka.net adds a random number to the Actor name Even if  i provided the name explicitly, example :

```
var VotingServer= System.ActorOf(Props.Create(()=> new VotingServerActor()),"VotingServerActor");
```

but Akka.net adds a random number to this actor making it impossible to address remotely.

i have searched everywhere and i have read the docs and i could not find anything, can someone tell me how to stop this random naming

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using Akka is to not address the actors separately.
Just call actorRef to get the actors.

```
var VotingServer= System.ActorOf(Props.Create(()=> new VotingServerActor()),"VotingServerActor"); 
var message = new VotingMessage();
VotingServer.Tell(message,Sender);
```